# ajax and jquery: submitting a form to have a modal div updated 

Tags: jquery

When the user clicks a link I have a modal pop up that has a form on it that submits to a php script.  I want that php scripts output to populate the modal pop up (which is essentially a div).  At the same time I want to submit a form that is beneath the modal pop up form.  I want to use ajax and this is what I have so far:

```
$('.window .submitlink').click(function (e) {

    /* Form 1 */
    $('#form2').live('submit', function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#dialog',
        url:    'signincode.php'
     });
    return false;
    });
    /* Form 2 */
    $('#form1').live('submit', function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
       //target: '#divLookup',
        url:    'index.php',
    });
    return false;
}); });
```

I can't seem to get this to work.  Any ideas?

Thanks for you help,

Ramona

Answer (score 0):

You need to [specify a `success` parameter to the ajax command](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that updates the DOM elements. Basically return the data you need to update the DOM from the php function, and use that to change the DOM with jQuery.

```
$(this).ajax({
  //target: '#divLookup',
  url:    'index.php',
  success: function(data) {
    // use the stuff contained in 'data' (which is just everything returned
    // from the php script, and visible in Firebug) to modify DOM elements
  }
});
```